# which is better foo::bar() VS $foo::bar()?

Tags: php

About this:

```
class foo {
    public static function bar() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
```

What's difference between this:

```
foo::bar();
```

and this:

```
$obj = new foo();
$obj::bar();
```

Or not difference? Are both the right and the principles? Which is better?

Comment: pretty sure they are the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is no difference between them, but from my experience most often used form is `Foo::bar()`.

You can find some examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

There is static method example with usage:

```
<?php

  class Foo {
     public static function aStaticMethod() {
      // ...
     }
  }

  Foo::aStaticMethod();
  $classname = 'Foo';
  $classname::aStaticMethod(); // As of PHP 5.3.0

?>
```

After that you can find example with accessing properties:

```
print Foo::$my_static . "\n";

$foo = new Foo();
print $foo::$my_static . "\n";
```

It means that both ways are correct. It's up to you what to use.